# Vue: How to create custom HTTP method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

For example i want to use that like `Vue.http.apiCall`

Which proper way to define own functions in built-in plugins? Should i create own plugin for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use vue-resource (Evan You already announced its retirement last year: [link](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4)). Instead, you can use the Fetch API, and creating a plugin is not really necessary, just wrap the API calls in a method:

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        getResult: undefined,
        postResult: undefined,
        samplePostData: {
          title: 'foo',
          body: 'bar',
          userId: 1
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getSampleData() {
            fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then((result) => {
                    // sample callback
                    this.getResult = result;
                })
        },
        postSampleData() {
            fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
              method: 'post',
              body: JSON.stringify(this.samplePostData)
            }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((result) => {
            /* will return
              {
                id: 101
              }
              */
              this.postResult = result
            })
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <h2>Sample Get:</h2>
    <button v-on:click="getSampleData()">Click to Get Sample data</button>
    <div>{{getResult}}</div>
    <h2>Sample Post:</h2>
    <button v-on:click="postSampleData()">Click to Post Sample data</button>
    <div>{{postResult}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @baka A little more info. Personally I prefer async API calls with Vuex.

Answer (score 0):

For Vue.js, you can use vue-resource

https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource

With this plugin, you can make external API call with like this

```
// GET /someUrl
this.$http.get('/someUrl').then(response => {

  // get body data
  this.someData = response.body;

}, response => {
  // error callback
});
```

Comment: i understand but i want expand functionality of this resource for example by adding new method